# Why is container.value_type illegal in C++

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code is illegal:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<int, char> > v;
    v.push_back(v.value_type(0, 'a')); // *
}
```

I have to change * to

```
v.push_back(decltype(v)::value_type(0, 'a'));
```

for the code to work.

Why is the line marked * not allowed? What is the reason behind that rationale?

Comment: Cause it's a typedef not a real "member"...?

Answer (score 9):

The long and short is, it's because C has separate namespaces for types and variables, which means you can construct scenarios where it would be impossible to access members due to ambiguity in C++ if `.` could be used to access both member and type in this fashion. And changing the namespacing rules would break compatiblity with legal C code.

```
struct s1 { typedef int X; };
struct s2 { void X(); };
typedef struct s1 X;
struct s2 X;
int main() {
    X.X();
}
```

Now what? You can't tell from context what X.X is supposed to be.

That's why `.` and `::` are in the language- `X.X()` refers to a member function call, and `X::X` refers to a type.

Comment: In this program `X.X` clearly refer to `s2::X` since the name before the dot must be an object.

Comment: Not if dots could also be used to refer to types.

Comment: If we define that the name before the dot must be an object, there would be no ambiguity. Whether the name after the dot is an object or a type should not matter.

Answer (score 2):

`v` is an object, and `v.value_type` is attempting to access `value_type` as though it's a member of the object. That's incorrect because `value_type` belongs to the class, not the instance. (As a side note, typedefs always belong to the class because they are fixed at compile time... i.e. different instances can't have different copies.)

`decltype(v)` resolves to the underlying class type of the object `v`, so in this case it's equivalent to writing `std::vector<std::pair<int, char> >`. The scope operator `::` is then used to let you access class items.

Some other languages don't bother making a distinction between member and class access operators (`.` and `::`). C++ has both largely for historical reasons related to C.

Comment: However, if `static_member` is a static member of `some_class`, we can use `object.static_member` to access that static member of the class, even though that `static_member` belongs to the class, not the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Because operators `.` and `->` are for member access(usually). You can't access anything abstract with it, only tangible objects. And type is an abstract thing. So you have to access it with `::`